# OpenCV matrix operations cause color corruption for YUV image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I’m trying to do image stabilization on an OpenCV image that’s in a YUV format where there are 2 channels: one containing the Y values, the other containing alternating U/V values (YUV_YUY2 in OpenCV).

The issue I’m having is that certain matrix operations, specifically warpAffine and resize, can shift the array such that the U values end up in the V positions and vice versa, inverting the colors or causing striping in the image.

My first thought was that I could just convert the image to a different (non-interleaved) image type, apply the transformation, and then convert back, but from the available transforms using cvtColor() that I've found: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html

I can convert from YUV_YUY2 to other formats, but there is no available conversion back to YUV_YUY2 format.

I may be able to manually reconstruct the YUY2 matrix, but I suspect there’s probably an easier way that I’m missing. Any OpenCV gurus have any suggestions? Thanks.

Code snippet:

```
cv::Mat stabilize (VideoFrame* curFrame, VideoFrame* prevFrame)
{
   Mat locCurMat, locPrevMat;
   locCurMat = Mat(1080, 1920, CV_8UC2, curFrame->video);
   locPrevMat = Mat(1080, 1920, CV_8UC2, prevFrame->video);

   // Calculate the transformation matrix
   Mat locTransform;
   // I’ll spare you this part
   // …

   // Apply the transformation
   Mat locStabFrame;
   // Make the border value (0, 128) for black: 
   // If you leave it at 0,0 it's bright green
   Scalar locBorderVal(0, 128);
   warpAffine(locCurMat, locStabFrame, locTransform, locCurMat.size(),
              INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, locBorderVal);

   // Crop the borders to make the video look better
   // Get the aspect ratio correct
   int locVertBorder = HORIZONTAL_BORDER_CROP * 
                       locCurMat.rows / locCurMat.cols;
   locStabFrame = locStabFrame(
       Range(locVertBorder, locStabFrame.rows - locVertBorder),
       Range(HORIZONTAL_BORDER_CROP,
             locStabFrame.cols - HORIZONTAL_BORDER_CROP));

   // Resize locStabFrame back to the proper frame size
   resize(locStabFrame, locStabFrame, locCurMat.size());

   // Return the stabilized result
   return locStabFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, here's the process I took to avoid this problem. It's slooow though, and if anyone has a more efficient way I would be glad to hear it.

The steps are basically:

1. Create masks for the u values and v values in the 2 channel YUV
2. Convert from 2 channel YUV to RGB
3. Run warpAffine & resize on RGB image
4. Convert RGB to 3 channel YUV
5. Use u/v masks to reconstruct 2 channel YUV from 3 channel YUV
6. Return 2 channel YUV image

Code:

```
// Apply the transformation
Mat rgbFrame, stabFrame, outputFrame;
// Convert the frame to RGB
cvtColor(locCurMat, rgbFrame, COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUY2);

// Apply the image translation
warpAffine(rgbFrame, stabFrame, T, rgbFrame.size());

// Crop the borders to make the video look better
// Get the aspect ratio correct
int vert_border = HORIZONTAL_BORDER_CROP * locCurMat.rows / locCurMat.cols;
stabFrame = stabFrame(Range(vert_border, stabFrame.rows - vert_border),
                      Range(HORIZONTAL_BORDER_CROP,
                            stabFrame.cols - HORIZONTAL_BORDER_CROP));


// Resize regFrame back to the correct frame size
resize(stabFrame, stabFrame, rgbFrame.size());

// Convert back from RGB to YUV
// First, see if the u/v masks are the correct size, and populate them
// if not. Hopefully this only happens once
if (locCurMat.rows != m_uMask.rows || locCurMat.cols != m_uMask.cols)
{
     printf("Creating U/V image masks\n");
     m_uMask = cv::Mat::zeros(locCurMat.size(), CV_8UC1);
     m_vMask = cv::Mat::zeros(locCurMat.size(), CV_8UC1);
     cv::Mat onesCol = cv::Mat::ones(locCurMat.rows, 1, CV_8UC1);
     // Populate the masks with alternating columns of 1s
     for (int i = 0; i < locCurMat.cols; i++)
     {
         // Copy even columns to the u mask
         if (i % 2 == 0)
         {
             onesCol.copyTo(m_uMask.col(i));
         }
         // Copy odd columns to the v mask
         else
         {
             onesCol.copyTo(m_vMask.col(i));
         }
      }
  }

// Convert the stabilized rgb frame to YUV
Mat yuvFrame;
cvtColor(stabFrame, yuvFrame, COLOR_RGB2YUV);

// Split the YUV frame into individual channels
vector<Mat> yuv3Channels;
split(yuvFrame, yuv3Channels);

// Copy the 3 channel YUV values into 2 channel YUV
vector<Mat> yuv2Channels;
Mat uvChannel;
yuv3Channels[1].copyTo(uvChannel, m_uMask);
yuv3Channels[2].copyTo(uvChannel, m_vMask);
yuv2Channels.push_back(yuv3Channels[0]);
yuv2Channels.push_back(uvChannel);

// Merge the 2 channel yuv back into the output frame
cv::merge(yuv2Channels, outputFrame);
```

Comment: Seems like a big hole in the API not to be able to convert back to YUY2, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it seems odd that they'll let you convert out of that format, but not back into it.